# How to correctly align arrow tip

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I have got this code:

```
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, text width=2em, minimum height=2em]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 3cm, auto]
    \node [block] (a) {A};
    \node [block, right of=a] (b) {B};
    \node [block, right of=b] (c) {C};

    \path [draw, ->, ultra thick] (a) -- (b);
    \path [draw, ->, ultra thick] (b) -- (c);
    \path [draw, ->, ultra thick, dashed] (c.south) |- ++(0pt,-20pt) |- ++(-170pt,-20pt) |- (a.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Which produces this graph:
[image]

I would like to align the arrow tip direction at the center of **A**. Can you help me please?

Comment: Change the second last line to `\path [draw, ->, ultra thick, dashed] (c.south) |- ([yshift=-20pt]a.south) -- (a.south);`. The reason why the arrow tip is turned is that `a.south` is a tiny bit to the left of the coordinate that you are shifting to with `++(0pt,-20pt) |- ++(-170pt,-20pt)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've used the operation `|-` too many times. These operation `|-` makes it possible to draw two lines, the first **vertical**, the second **horizontal**.

First : You arrive at the bottom left, then just go directly to A with the operation `line to`   `--`.

[image: chemin-tikz]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, text width=2em, minimum height=2em]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 3cm, auto]
    \node [block] (a) {A};
    \node [block, right of=a] (b) {B};
    \node [block, right of=b] (c) {C};
    \path [draw, ->, ultra thick] (a) -- (b);
    \path [draw, ->, ultra thick] (b) -- (c);
    \path [draw, ->, ultra thick, dashed] (c.south) |-  ++(-170pt,-20pt) -- (a.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** In order to correct the vertical as noticed by @JasperHabicht

In order for the last arrow to be effectively vertical, a point under block `A` can be defined with a distance of `20 pt`.

```
\coordinate[below of=a,node distance=20pt](d);
```

[image: chemin-tikz-corrige]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, text width=2em, minimum height=2em]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 3cm, auto]
    \node [block] (a) {A};
    \node [block, right of=a] (b) {B};
    \node [block, right of=b] (c) {C};
    \coordinate[below of=a,node distance=20pt](d); 
    \path [draw, ->, ultra thick] (a) -- (b);
    \path [draw, ->, ultra thick] (b) -- (c);
    \path [draw, ->, ultra thick, dashed] (c.south) |-  ++(d) -| (a.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that the last segment of the dashed line is slightly slanted. It may be better to shift down from `a.south` using `yshift` for example. But nice answer (+1).

Comment: @JasperHabicht Indeed, I have not changed the parameters of the question.

Comment: Thanks so much both of you! Jasper's answer is more dynamic, so I'm using it instead.

Comment: @JasperHabicht I have corrected the verticality, feel free to answer this question by correcting the verticality in your own way.

Answer (score 4):

I would prefer to go without unnecessarily defining new coordinates.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{block/.style={rectangle, draw, text width=2em, minimum height=2em}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 3cm, auto]
    \node [block] (a) {A};
    \node [block, right of=a] (b) {B};
    \node [block, right of=b] (c) {C};
    \draw[->, ultra thick] (a) -- (b);
    \draw[->, ultra thick] (b) -- (c);
    \draw[->, ultra thick, dashed] (c.south) -- ++(0,-20pt) -| (a);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @marmot be my guest and edit it as you wish. I am not even remotely a TikZ answerer :)